# Rails - Strong Params on a Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, strong-parameters

My controllers need to create more than one model. I could use nested attributes to whitelist the params. However I would have strong params for the same models all over the place and whenever I changed one of the models I would have to change all the strong params.

To solve this, I found this idea of creating a module with the strong params and call them in the controllers.
I am new to rails, so I would like to know if this is a good or bad pattern/idea??

Comment: That would be a perfectly acceptable design pattern, IMHO.

Comment: Great! Thanks NickM!!